# MS Word VBA Selection.Range only works after 1st page

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using the following code to insert my signature after writing a report.  The template for the report is pre-determined, and I cannot change or add tags/bookmarks to it.  Our admin fills out the top part, and then sends the corresponding person the document. After which we write it up.

```
Sub Signature()
Dim pic As Shape

Set pic = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:="C:\My Documents\My Pictures\CompressSig.png", _
            LinkToFile:=False, _
            SaveWithDocument:=True, _
            Left:=0, _
            Top:=-25, _
            Width:=140, _
            Height:=50, _
            Anchor:=Selection.Range)
            pic.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind

End Sub
```

The problem is, on my one page reports, it will stay at the top left, unless I manually adjust the Top/Left attributes. If it's a two page report, the signature goes right where the cursor is (which is where I want it to go).  Why is selection.range only working on the first page and/or is there something else I can do?  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

A shape's *anchor* is not it's **position**. Instead, it is the paragraph to which the shape is **anchored**. Here's an explanation of [how anchors work](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008229_Understanding_Object_Anchors.html).

You probably don't want a Shape. Instead, use **InlineShape**. This inserts a shape inline with text, which makes more sense for a signature.

But wait! Word already has a feature to do what you want! Building blocks (or AutoText) can save a graphic to your template. You can save your signature as a building block, then give that entry a keyboard shortcut and place your signature wherever the insertion point is blinking. No programming required.